# Understanding the JPA mappedBy attribute in a OneToMany relationship

Tags: jpa

I am looking at examples of defining relationships between entities, and was unsure of what the mapped by in the onetomany relationship references. Is it the name of a table column, or the name of a class?

```
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "company")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of the above. It's the name of the attribute/property of the other side of the association. So for example:

```
public class Car {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "theCar")
    private List<Wheel> wheels;
}

public class Wheel {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "COL_CAR")
    private Car theCar;
}
```

In the above example, `mappedBy = "theCar"` means: I'm the inverse side of the bidirectional association which is mapped by the attribute `theCar` in the class `Wheel`.

And in the class Wheel, the association defines how the association is mapped: using a join column named `COL_CAR`.

Comment: And the COL_CAR column is a part of the Car class in this example?

Comment: No. The COL_CAR column is part of the table WHEEL. Every row in WHEEL has a column COL_CAR, which contains the ID of the CAR that the wheel belongs to.

Comment: Thanks! ON a related note, how would I specify when only one side of the relationship knows about the other? For example, my Team class has an arraylist of Contacts, but the Contact class does not know about the team? How would I specify this one way relationship (unidirectional)

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#collections-mapping